# How to unwrap paragraphs using sed

Tags: sed

I have a text file that contains paragraphs wrapped at 76 characters with an empty line between paragraphs.  I'd like to use sed to convert this to a file that has one line per paragraph, no blank lines.

Example input:

```
Start of p1
continued p1
end of p1.

Start of p2
end of p2.

Start of p3
continued p3
even more p3
end of p3.
```

Example output:

```
Start of p1 continued p1 end of p1.
Start of p2 end of p2.
Start of p3 continued p3 even more p3 end of p3.
```

Comment: Similar question for VIM at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11039544/3478507

Comment: why use `sed` when `fmt` and `par` are designed for exactly this job (reformatting paragraphs), and will do it better than anything you can write in a sed script?  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @cas: okay, i'll bite. I looked at the manpage for `fmt`; it requires a value for the maximum line width -- something that is unknown a priori in this type of use case.  The manpage for `par` is by its own admission not well-written for the end user.

Comment: the maximum line width for fmt is whatever you want it to be.  par's documentation may be complex but that doesn't mean it's impossible to use...it just means that it has lots of options that are useful in different circumstances, to produce variously formatted output.

Comment: It may not be relevant to the typical use case but it might be worth noting that the maximum line width of GNU [`fmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/fmt-invocation.html) is 2500 characters. This is the current state as of GNU Coretutils 9.3 and has been that way [for quite a while](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/c5c14638098256dcdad1c205299c49812a91e0aa/src/fmt.c#L394).

Comment: Of greater practical relevance might be that even using a very large width setting with `fmt` does not necessarily result in an exact unwrapping. At least for the case where a paragraph contains multiple sentences it seems that both GNU and BSD `fmt` will insert at least one additional blank between those two sentences (this assumption is based purely on empirical evidence, so please correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### With GNU sed

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!{/\n$/!ba}; s/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g' textfile
Start of p1 continued p1 end of p1. 
Start of p2 end of p2. 
Start of p3 continued p3 even more p3 end of p3.
```

How it works

- `:a`

  This defines the label `a`
- `N`

  This reads in the next line and appends it, along with a newline character, to the current line.
- `$!{/\n$/!ba}`

  If (a) we are not at the end of the file *and* (b) the current line is not empty, then jump (branch) back to label `a`
- `s/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g'`

  If we get here, we have a complete paragraph in the pattern space.  Look for all newline characters, optionally preceded or followed by blanks, and replace it with a blank.

#### With BSD/OSX sed

Try (untested):

```
sed -e :a -e 'N;$!{/\n$/!ba' -e '}' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]*/ /g' textfile
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '{printf "%s ",$0} /^$/{print ""} END{print ""}' text
Start of p1 continued p1 end of p1.  
Start of p2 end of p2.  
Start of p3 continued p3 even more p3 end of p3.
```